# Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: an array"

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I have a web to check somebody's salary. Every time an icon is clicked, the data of the salary will be sent to the firebase. But it constantly gives me an error.
Err : FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: an array

My database consists of a list of people and each person has the details of their salary, in an array, such as overtime pay, meal allowance, basic salary etc.

Here is my data

```
data(){return{newSalary: {basicSalary:null, overtimePay:null, mealAllowance:null}}}
```

and here is my method

```
    async addGaji(rowIndex){  
        let values = Object.values(this.newSalary);
        if (values.includes(null)){
            showToast({
                message: "Input is missing",
                color: "red"
            });
            console.log(this.operators[rowIndex].originalData.salary)
        } else {
            await db.collection('operator').doc(this.operators[rowIndex].originalData.salary).push(this.newSalary)
            .then(() => {
                showToast({
                    message: "Data has been uploaded",
                    color:"blue"
                })
            })
            .catch(console.log(this.operators[rowIndex].originalData.salary));
        }                         
    }
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?
I've already use concat because I thought it can join new array to the existing array inside firebase salary data